# Categorize values in Redis... should I use sets or keys?

Tags: redis

Long story short. I have thousands of entries that belongs to one of 6 possible categories:

```
foo => category1
bar => category2
baz => category3
lol => category1
```

Storing key=>values looks kind of weird, since I will be repeating the values a bunch of times. So I was thinking about using 6 sets containing each element.

My app receives a key and must return the category it belongs to. If I use only key=>values approach, it's as simple as querying that key. If I use sets I'd have to query each set looking for my item:

```
if SISMEMBER category1 "baz";
  return category1
if SISMEMBER category2 "baz";
  return category2
if SISMEMBER category3 "baz";
  return category3
```

What would be the best way to go in this case? Besides performance and space considerations is there anything I should be considering here?

Comment: If a key can belong to more than one category then I would use PIPELINING to fetch all the SISMEMBER result together.

Comment: Will keep that in mind. In this case, a key can belong to just one category.

Answer (score 0):

Use hashmap or key-value to store item=>category relation, then you can use *multiple operation to determine the category of each item, that will be a great improvement of performance compares to determine one by one.

Example:

```
hset('rel', item1, cat1);
hset('rel', item2, cat2);
...
hmget('rel', array(item1, item2)); // return array(item1=>cat1, item2=>cat2);
```

And use set/hashmap/zset to group items together by categories;

Comment: Every time using HSETS for store thousands of entries with similar  key names your should keep in your mind http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11281734/redis-using-hashes, http://instagram-engineering.tumblr.com/post/12202313862/storing-hundreds-of-millions-of-simple-key-value-pairs and http://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization.